# Data not showing in my console.log in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

In my vue app I have 2 methods, one method gets some data from my laravel backend and the second one needs to be able to grab it so that I can use it in that method.
What I'm struggling with is that the second method isn't grabbing the data.

Here is my code

```
    <template>
        <app-layout>
            <div class="content-wrapper" style="margin-left: 0;">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row pt-5">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                Some data will show here
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </app-layout>
    </template>

    <script>
    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout'
    export default {
        components: {
            AppLayout,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                testData: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            firstMethod() {
                axios.get('/api/get-data').then(response => {
                    this.testData = response.data;
                });
            },
            secondMethod(){
                console.log(this.testData);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.firstMethod();
            this.secondMethod();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: you will be able to see the log in you console, but if it is empty so the secondMethod will be call before the assigning your api response to the testData variable. Call the secondMethod in the response of your api.

Comment: Hey!Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

your running both function in mount function so both run at same time and `secondMethod()` executed 1st at that time  your `this.testData` is not set so you can use `async` and `await` to wait to finish `firstMethod()` then run `secondMethod()`

which will be like below code

```html
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <div class="content-wrapper" style="margin-left: 0">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row pt-5">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            Some data will show here
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/AppLayout";
export default {
    components: {
        AppLayout,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            testData: "",
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async firstMethod() {
            const { data } = await axios.get("/api/get-data");
            this.testData = data;
        },
        secondMethod() {
            console.log(this.testData);
        },
    },
    async mounted() {
        await this.firstMethod();
        this.secondMethod();
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm still not getting any of my data

Comment: are you getting response?

Comment: did you try printing the data in your console before assigning it to testData?

Comment: @Aurilie check in vue dev tool `testData` have any value or not

Comment: So I had a look again when I did the `console.log` it was in my for loop and that was where it wasn't showing up

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling firstMethod in created() hook instead of mounted. In my opinion you do not need a method for modifying incoming data. Use watch instead:

```
watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    testData: function (newValue) {
      // do what transformation you need here
    }
  }
```

Watch hooks run when value of variable changes, so it should run when it is assigned.

Comment: I'm not very good when it comes to the watch method. Would it be possible for you to show me how it would work together

Comment: Yes, create the watch as I showed in previous comment and it will wait for updates to this variable. Whenever the value of testData changes, the code inside the watch will run. Whatever operation you want to do in secondMethod, you will do it in this watch function. I hope it is clear. You can also check Vue's official documentation on watch properties, it is pretty good and they advise you to use it when fetching data from API such as this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you dont see the console log is because even if you execute first the first method, it's actually executed after the second method because takes more time to be resolved.

Try the below please, inside first method i added after `then` to execute the second method which means that that the first method would be resolved, thus we will have the api response.

In case you continue seeing nothing from console log then there is an issue with the api endpoint.

```
 mounted() {
   this.firstMethod();
},

       methods: {
            firstMethod() {
                axios.get('/api/get-data').then(response => {
                    
                    this.testData = response.data;
                    this.secondMethod();
                });
            },
            secondMethod(){
                console.log(this.testData);
            }
        },
```